# Cloudfunction v2 invoked by pubsub logs "Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

I've created a cloudfunction v2 that's invoked by a pubsub topic/subscription messagePublished event. However, whenever it's triggered, I get this error:

```
{
httpRequest: {
latency: "0s"
protocol: "HTTP/1.1"
remoteIp: "xx.xxx.xx.xx"
requestMethod: "POST"
requestSize: "3912"
requestUrl: "https://handler-function-cloud-custodian-xxxxxx-uc.a.run.app/?__GCP_CloudEventsMode=CUSTOM_PUBSUB_projects%2Fchase-test-custodian%2Ftopics%2Fevent-topic-cloud-custodian"
serverIp: "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
status: 403
userAgent: "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)"
}
insertId: "xxxxx"
labels: {
goog-managed-by: "cloudfunctions"
}
logName: "projects/chase-test-custodian/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-01-30T17:45:14.427320714Z"
resource: {
labels: {5}
type: "cloud_run_revision"
}
severity: "WARNING"
spanId: "xxxxxx"
textPayload: "The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"
timestamp: "2023-01-30T17:45:14.422306Z"
trace: "projects/chase-test-custodian/traces/xxxxxx"
}
```

I tried adding the "allUsers" principal with "Cloud Functions Invoker" role to the cloud function, but I get the same error regardless.

The subscription was created by terraform when I specified it as the cloudfunctions iam member using the tf in the below gist:
https://gist.github.com/chase-replicated/0aa241db7da7e31fa63601fcd3308e91

Comment: was you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need to grant permission to the service account associated with the [function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity) for Google to authorise the function , You can also try creating a new service account for the function.

But I would suggest creating a [case](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to Google Cloud for this as they may dig through your logs and monitoring. (and possibly your available service accounts) for investigation.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this in the GUI by going to the cloud run that gets associated with the cloudfunctionv2 - you can see the association as in this pic in the top right of the function in the GUI:
[image: link to cloud run]

Here you can set "allow unauthenticated invocations". This works for me with  "allUsers" set also.

However I haven't found a solution to deploying this with terraform yet. I know how to create a cloudrun service with unauthenticated invocations but I don't know how to grab the associated cloudrun service automatically generated with the function :/

I will update this if I do.

**Update:**

I got the above to work with terraform by using the code below. The idea is to manage the cloud run IAM policy and reference the function as the service:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "public_invoker" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "allUsers",
    ]
  }
}


resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "public_access_function" {
  project = google_cloudfunctions2_function.My_Function.project
  location = google_cloudfunctions2_function.My_Function.location
  service = google_cloudfunctions2_function.My_Function.name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.public_invoker.policy_data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from a gen1 cloud function, they have changed the role that is needed for the trigger. For gen1 functions you needed `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` but for gen2 functions you need `roles/run.invoker`.

I can see in your gist, that you create a gen2 function (`google_cloudfunctions2_function`) but still assign the old IAM role here: https://gist.github.com/chase-replicated/0aa241db7da7e31fa63601fcd3308e91#file-gistfile1-txt-L89

This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating?&_ga=2.181528807.-1929129748.1687846723&_gac=1.54319578.1688368648.Cj0KCQjw7uSkBhDGARIsAMCZNJvfHh-VEoDnBTQpcf2ny46_c5d--oXU_2bN-8GscAeQoj1uDTQz2hAaAuNeEALw_wcB#authenticating_function_to_function_calls)

Answer (score 0):

The error says: ""The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header."

This happens because two things are true: First, the Cloud Function that you are executing does not allow unauthenticated invocations. You can change this by modifying the Cloud Function. And second, the (push) subscription in Pub/Sub that delivers the message to the Cloud Function does not have authentication enabled. So you can also change the subscription to enable authentication.